# Magento 1.9.3 - Can we override Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien class?

Tags: overrides, magento1.9.3, override-model

I am trying to override `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien` class but not getting success.

My `config.xml` file -

```
 <models>
        <coreoverride>
            <class>Test_CoreOverride_Model</class>               
        </coreoverride>
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <session_abstract_varien>Test_CoreOverride_Model_Core_Session_Abstract_Varien</session_abstract_varien>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
    </models>
```

My custom model (`Varien.php`) file -

```
class Test_CoreOverride_Model_Core_Session_Abstract_Varien extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien {

    public function start($sessionName = null) {      
        Mage::log('override success...', null, 'override.log');
    }

}
```

Just want to know that can we do override this class or not? If yes, what is the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overwrite this way for this abstract class. Make a copy in local directory and modify what you want. But be careful for upcoming release if magento modify this class then you need to adjust that too.

New location will be:

**app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php**